# Really Easy PHP query. Displaying from separate PHP file

Tags: php

I'm a PHP n00b. I have this code, however it is on my main page. I assume like jQuery there must be a way to display this without having the actual script on the main document that the users access?

Or is there a way I can do this tidier without echo'ing everything?

```
        include('talentsearch.php');

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result2))
        {
        echo "<div class='talent_result_wrapper' data-experience='" . $row['divTagExp'] . "' data-salary='" . $row['divTagExp'] . "'>";
        echo "<ul>";
        echo "<li><strong>Talent ID:  </strong>" . $row['CandidateID'] . "</li>";
        echo "<li><strong>Resides:  </strong>" . $row['Town'] . "</li>";
        echo "<li><strong>Salary Required:  </strong>£" . $row['SalaryMin'] . "</li>";
        echo "<li><strong>Experience:  </strong>" . $row['CandidateExperience'] . " Years </li>";
        echo "<li><strong>Industy:  </strong>" . $row['PrimarySector'] . "</li>";
        echo "<li><strong>Specialism:  </strong>" . $row['PrimarySector'] . "</li>";
        echo "</div>";
        }
```

I have tried putting it in a function like this:

```
function getTalent() {

}
```

And then calling the function like this

```
<?php
include('talentsearch.php');
getTalent()
?>
```

But I get an error whereas I don't if I just run the code normally.

```
Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in
```

So I assume I'm not doing it right.

Comment: whats in getTalent function?

Comment: Where's `$result2` supposed to be defined? Currently it's `null` and that's what's causing the error.

Comment: Whatever you are passing to `mysqli_fetch_array()` does not exist inside the function. It is not global or not defined when you call the function.

Comment: I have this: `$result2 = mysqli_query($con,$sql2);`. So do I need to have this and `$con` and `$sql2` within the function? Would it maybe be easier to call it by using jQuery or something?

Comment: @tonoslfx everything after `while` in the first code bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is this what you are trying to achive?

```
talentsearch.php file

function getTalent($row) {

     return "<div class='talent_result_wrapper' data-experience='" . $row['divTagExp'] . "' data-salary='" . $row['divTagExp'] . "'>
        <ul>
          <li><strong>Talent ID:  </strong>" . $row['CandidateID'] . "</li>
          <li><strong>Resides:  </strong>" . $row['Town'] . "</li>
          <li><strong>Salary Required:  </strong>£" . $row['SalaryMin'] . "</li>
          <li><strong>Experience:  </strong>" . $row['CandidateExperience'] . " Years </li>
          <li><strong>Industy:  </strong>" . $row['PrimarySector'] . "</li>
          <li><strong>Specialism:  </strong>" . $row['PrimarySector'] . "</li>
           </div>";
    }

/////// 
main.php file     
include('talentsearch.php');

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)) {
  echo getTalent($row);
}
```

Comment: Would this still need to go into the main php page? I'm trying to have the code in a php doc that the user never directly accesses, but calls from it via the page they do access. Just to be clear, the code does work as is, I just want to move it out of the main php doc.